# Change CRLF to LF for all files in a PyCharm project

Tags: pycharm

I want to change CRLF to LF for all files in a project that I have opened in PyCharm. I have updated project settings to use LF line separator from
"File -> Settings -> Editor -> Code Style" It does not change existing files without opening these.

Is there any way to change CRLF to LF for all existing files in PyCharm?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

- Step 1

Select **root** node in project view

[image]

- Step 2

Click File menu like the following:

[image]

**Note**: If there are many files the process seems stuck, don't worry, just wait.

Comment: If you only need to change a part of a large project, you may wish to be more selective as to which parts of the project are selected to avoid a long wait